# Connection between Chladni Plates and Projective Geometry?

Tags: projective-geometry, projective-space, projective-module, projective-schemes, stereographic-projections

Does anybody know of a connection between Chladni Plates and Projective Geometry? Any published research on the subject? I am interested to know if Chladni Plates (or surfaces) can be explained/expressed in projective-geometric terms.

Chladni Plates
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ernst_Chladni#Chladni_figures

Chladni plate interference surfaces
http://paulbourke.net/geometry/chladni/

Comment: Out of curiosity, is there any reason to expect the answer is "yes"? (Naively, I'd expect research focuses on (eigenfunctions of) the Laplacian of a plane region through the relationship with the linear wave equation...but I'm certainly no expert.)

Comment: This may be an invalid question. Frankly, compared to you and most others on this site I am just a "Mathematics Spectator."  I have interest in these topics and I am simply curious. The answer to this question maybe "Dude, you don't know what you are asking" in which case, I can remove the question, or a moderator can do likewise.

Comment: There's no harm in asking. It merely seemed prudent to ask if you had some potential connection in mind. :)

Comment: In my limited understanding, Projective Geometry has a "Harmonic Pencil" for generating conic sections. Which is very beautiful. Projective Geometry appears to be a "more fundamental" geometry than Euclidean geometry and other comparable geometries. Music has much to do with Harmonies (although I don't know if there is a connection between music and conics).. so again.. just curious what others think.